# scrolling layer of composite sprite backgrounds

Tags: ios, background, cocos2d-iphone, scroll, layer

Each of the backgrounds in my game is represented by a one to five images layered on each other. How can I make these composite sprite backgrounds and add a maximum of three backgrounds to the layer in such a way that I can scroll through them. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Use CCScrollLayer Extension.

You can download it from [here](https://github.com/cocos2d/cocos2d-iphone-extensions/tree/master/Extensions/CCScrollLayer)